# Perl help: Can't call method "display" on an undefined value

Tags: linux, perl, cgi

Let start with the basic back ground. We recently brought our web hosting in house.
There are few old website still use Perl. I have no experience with Perl.
Let's Begin. We have a this sub website on our main domain.

Public link : [http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/](http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap)

When you goto website we get the following error message

```
 "Software error:

Can't call method "display" on an undefined value at /var/www/www.gatewayrehab.org/app/webroot/eap/index.cgi line 47."
```

Looking at the EAP website/directory all files look in place with proper permission, again I have no experience with Perl/Cgi. Below is the index.cgi file :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

### the main control file used in the system
BEGIN { unshift @INC, qw(./cgi-bin/include/); }

### send all fatal errors to the browser
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);
use Error_Handler;
use File_Handler;
use Cookie_Handler;

require "./cgi-bin/setup.cgi";
do "./cgi-bin/include/common.cgi";

### initialize the file handling module
my $File = new File_Handler;
### initialize the cookie handling module
my $Cookie = new Cookie_Handler;

###parse 
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST"){
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
} else {
    $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

#&error_check;

foreach $pair (@pairs){
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $name =~ tr/+/ /;
    $name =~ s/\breq\_//ig;
    $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $name =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    $name = trim($name);
    $FORM{$name} = trim($value);
}

my %cookiedata = $Cookie -> get_cookies();

### read the summary database
my $summary_ref = $File -> read($login_summary)|| $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);
my (@summary) = @$summary_ref;

### read the companies database
my $companies_ref = $File -> read($companies_db)|| $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);
my (@companies) = @$companies_ref;

my %COMP = ();
foreach (@companies) {
    $_ =~ s/\n|\r//g;
    my ($c_num, $c_name) = split(/\t/, $_);
    $COMP{$c_num} = $c_name;
}

if ( $cookiedata{'LOGIN'} != 1 ) {
    my $found = 0;
    my $company_number = $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'};
    $company_number =~ s/s|e|w//g;

    foreach (@summary) {
        $_ =~ s/\n|\r//g;
        my @field = split(/\t/, $_);
        $field[0] = &trim($field[0]);
        $field[2] = &trim($field[2]);       
        $field[3] = &trim($field[3]);
        $field[4] = &trim($field[4]);
        $field[5] = &trim($field[5]);
        $field[6] = &trim($field[6]);

        if ( $field[0] eq "$company_number" ) {
            $found = 1;

            my $firstletters = substr($ENV{'REMOTE_USER'}, 0, 2);
            $firstletters = trim($firstletters);
            if ( $firstletters ne "sw" && $firstletters ne "lf" ) {
                $firstletters = substr($firstletters, 0, 1);
            }
            if ( lc($firstletters) eq "e" ) {
                $field[3] = ($field[3] + 1);                
            } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "s" ) {
                $field[2] = ($field[2] + 1);
            } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "w" ) {
                $field[4] = ($field[4] + 1);
            } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "sw" ) {
                $field[5] = ($field[2] + 1);
            } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "lf" ) {
                $field[6] = ($field[6] + 1);
            } else {
                $field[3] = ($field[3] + 1);
            }           

            $_ = join("\t", @field);
        } 
    }

    if ( $found == 1 ) {
        # write data back to file
        # append to summary file
        open(LOG, ">$login_summary") || $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);
        flock(LOG,2);
        foreach (@summary) {
            print LOG $_ ."\n";
        }
        flock(LOG,8);
        close(LOG);         
        #$File -> file($login_summary);
        #$File -> data(\@summary);
        #$File -> write() || $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__); 
    } else {
        $e = 0;
        $s = 0;
        $w = 0;
        $sw = 0;
        $lf = 0;

        my $firstletters = substr($ENV{'REMOTE_USER'}, 0, 2);
        $firstletters = trim($firstletters);
        if ( $firstletters ne "sw" && $firstletters ne "lf" ) {
            $firstletters = substr($firstletters, 0, 1);
        }
        if ( lc($firstletters) eq "e" ) {
            $e = 1;         
        } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "s" ) {
            $s = 1;
        } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "w" ) {
            $w = 1;
        } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "sw" ) {
            #$sw = 1;
            $s = 1;
        } elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "lf" ) {
            $lf = 1;
        } else {
            $e = 1;
        }

        # append to summary file
        open(LOG, ">>$login_summary") || $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);
        flock(LOG,2);
        print LOG $company_number ."\t". $COMP{$company_number} ."\t". $s ."\t". $e ."\t". $w . "\t". $sw ."\t". $lf ."\n";
        flock(LOG,8);
        close(LOG); 
    }

    my (@login_logs) = ();
    my $logline = "";
    $login_logs[0] = $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'};
    $login_logs[1] = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
    $login_logs[2] = time();

    open(LOG, ">>$login_logs") || $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);
    flock(LOG,2);
    print LOG $ENV{'REMOTE_USER'} ."\t". $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} ."\t". time() ."\n";
    flock(LOG,8);
    close(LOG);

    print "Set-Cookie: LOGIN=1";
    print "; path=$cookiepath; domain=$cookiedomain;\n";    
}

my $firstletters = substr($ENV{'REMOTE_USER'}, 0, 2);
$firstletters = trim($firstletters);
if ( $firstletters ne "sw" && $firstletters ne "lf") {
    $firstletters = substr($firstletters, 0, 1);
}

if ( lc($firstletters) eq "e" ) {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/new/employee/member.htm\n\n";          
} elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "s" ) {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/supervisor/\n\n";
} elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "w" ) {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/new/worklife/member.htm\n\n";
} elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "sw" ) {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/supervisor-wl/\n\n";
    exit;
} elsif ( lc($firstletters) eq "lf" ) {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/legalandfinancial/\n\n";
    exit;
} else {
    print "Location: http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/new/employee/member.htm\n\n";
}

#output html
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<h1>hello world!</h1>";

$e = `perl -ver`;
$r = `whereis perl5`;
$z = `whereis sendmail`;#
$w = `top`;#
$d = `w`;

print "<pre>perl version:<br>$e<hr>perl path:<br>$r<hr>sendmail path:<br>$z<hr>top:<br>$w<hr>w:<br>$d<hr>environment vars:<br>";##

while (($key, $val) = each %ENV) {
    print "$key = $val\n";
}


$x= 'lowercase';
print "<hr>path tranlsated(NT)<br>$ENV{'PATH_TRANSLATED'}</pre>";
#$x = uc($x);
print "<br>$x";
exit;
```

Please let me know what I am missing. If you need to look at more "included" files let me know.

Also here is the link for our cgi config. http://www.gatewayrehab.org/eap/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi

Thank You.

Comment: While I sympathize with your situation, this question would fit this site better if had a "help me learn enough Perl to fix this" focus, rather than "here's everything I see; tell me what to do".

Comment: @ysth: Very true. But you someone was going to learn Perl then I'd really hope that they wouldn't start with this monstrosity of a program that looks like it was written in about 1996 :-/

Comment: @Dave Cross: you, sir, are not a maintenance programmer :)

Comment: Actually, a lot of the time I am. But an eternally optimistic one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem with a quick fix. I don't know why it work but it does for me.
Here what i did...After reading online i found that adding "-w" on the header of all .(dot)cgi files make it work.
I do hope there is a better method to add "-w" in one place then adding it on all .cgi files.

In short change `#!/usr/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`

Thanks all.

Comment: Enabling/disabling `-w` [warning flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#What's-wrong-with-*-w*-and-%24%5eW) won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from this line: `my $summary_ref = $File -> read($login_summary)|| $Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);`. It means `$Error` doesn't exist or its value is `undef`. And indeed, I don't see such a variable being declared or initialised. Maybe it's suppose to be exported by Error_Handler???

This error is happening when trying to report another error. You could try replacing (if only temporarily) `$Error -> display("$!". __LINE__);` with `die($!)` and checking your server's error log for the error message. That said, it's surely "No such file or directory" or "Permission denied", so maybe it's not worth the time to find out the exact message. (Upd: Actually, I think the message will be "redirected" to your browser, so that makes things easier.)

I'm guessing here, but it looks like it's trying to read the file named by `$login_summary`. I have no idea where this is set (if at all!), so you might want to find out its value, and maybe where it's getting set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried Changing the line with die($!). Got error back saying "No such file or Directory".
Let me add i did find login_summery.cgi in a folder name "logs". Please let me know where i can find the value of ($login_summery)

Answer (score 1):

As ikegami pointed out, the error you are seeing indicates that `$Error` is not being initialized, and looking at the rest of the script, I would guess that what is needed (first of all) is to initialize it in the same manner as the `$File` and `$Cookie` variables.  Add this line after line 20 in your script:

```
my $Error = new Error_Handler;
```

That might give you a nicer error message, but it will probably just tell you what you already discovered when you added your `die($!);` line: 'No such file or directory'.

Your script is also `do`ing a file called `./cgi-bin/include/common.cgi`.  Check this file for your `$login_summary` variable, to know what file it's trying to access.